# How to use routing in ASP.NET MVC to upload an image created on the fly to Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the C# Facebook SDK to post an image to a user's wall. I'd like the image to be created in-memory on the fly instead of having it stored on disk so I provide a link to a non-existing image in the Facebook post and route the request for this image to an action method that creates the image and return a FileContentResult. Code:

Global.asax.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.MapRoute(
      "ImageRoute",
      "image/{imageName}.png",
      new { controller = "Facebook", action = "GetImage" });
);
```

FacebookController.cs

```
public ActionResult PostAnImageAndMessageToFacebookWall()
{
   var parameters = new Dictionary<String, Object> { { "message", "A message to the Wall" }, 
                                                     { "picture", "http://my_app.com/image/my_image" + ".png")}};
   _facebookWebClient.Post("me/feed", parameters);
   return View();
}
public FileContentResult GetImage(string imageName)
{
   Image myImage = _imageService.CreateImage(imageName);
   var memStream = new MemoryStream();
   myImage.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   return new FileContentResult(memStream.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

If I type the address and routing values of my Facebook webapp in the browser it displays the image (i.e. http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/image/some_image_name.png) it displays the image. But the wall post doesn't display the image, only the message.
Why doesn't this work and is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

When I go to http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/GetImage/some_image_name.png I see Facebook HTML wrapped around an image living in an iFrame.  If you can give the URL directly to your image that would work much better. Such as www.example.com/myApp/GetImage/some_image_name.png

Comment: Mistyped the url above; it should not be 'GetImage' but just 'image' as specified in Global.asax.cs. Anyway, both http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/image/some_image_name.png and http://my_app.com/image/some_image_name.png works, i.e. the requests get routed to my web apps' GetImage method which creates an image on the fly and returns it. The problem is that the image isn't displayed in the post on the user's wall which seem to imply that when Facebook makes the request using the provided URL it fails, but why?

Comment: Again, when you request anything from apps.facebook.com/anything/image., take a look at the response stream.  As you can see the response from apps.facebook.com/my_app/image/some_image_name.png  is NOT an image.

Comment: I'll rephrase: when typing a certain URL in my browser's address field and pressing enter, an image is displayed. When posting the same URL to a user's facebook wall, the image is not displayed. Why not?

Comment: Seriously, take three seconds and look at view source for that link.  It is NOT a LINK to an IMAGE.  It is a link to a web page that happens to have many, many images. Your og:image MUST point to an image, not a web page.

Comment: I know that the link is not a link to an image, it's a link to nothing since it's just an example of how the link would look like given the code I've written in the question. I'm not posting a link and and therefore not using the og meta tags to display the image, I'm using the picture field of the post command as in the example I've given in the question.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/